# How to turn Integer-List Generator [m ...] in Lambda Calculus in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I have given a task to make the Integer-List Generator `[m...]` in lambda calculus.
So it should fullfill this definition.

`Y F m ≡ : m (Y F (+ m 1))`

Therefor a lambda calculus F is needed.
I don't know how to find which lambda calculus F should be.
Does anyone have any suggestions for F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equational reasoning gets you where you need to go. We have these two equations:

```
Y F = F (Y F) -- the basic useful property of Y
Y F m = : m (Y F (+ m 1))
```

So now we just solve. We replace the `Y F` in `Y F m = ...` with the thing it's equal to:

```
F (Y F) m = : m (Y F (+ m 1))
```

One solution to this equation is to generalize from `Y F` to an arbitrary variable `g` everywhere:

```
F g m = : m (g (+ m 1))
```

Done. This is now a fine defining equation for `F`. If you don't like the syntax sugar, you could instead write it as a lambda:

```
F = \g m -> : m (g (+ m 1))
```

Of course, when you practice this yourself on other problems, be kind to yourself: there are lots of different choices of how to rewrite things at each step, and you might have to play with a couple different ways before you stumble on one that gets you where you want to go, rather than following such a straight-line path as I've outlined here where I had already tried and eliminated a bunch of wrong ways. Persevere, and you can learn to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide some notes on the relationship of `[m..]` and `y f m = m : (y f (+ m 1))`. Starting with the observation

```
[m..] = m : [m+1..]
```

and replacing `[m..]` using `g m = [m..]`, we arrive at

```
g m = m : (g (m+1))
```

Taken as a definition of `g`, observe that this is a recursive definition. Recursive definitions can be split into a generic recursive part `y` (given by `y f = f (y f)`) and a non-recursive part `f`

```
g = y f
```

This replaces the recursive `g` by the non-recursive `f` which we still have to determine/solve for. Substituting `g` in the previous equation gives

```
y f m = m : (y f (m+1))
```

The take away message is that a recursive function (`g`) can be refactored into a non-recursive function (`f`). All you need is a single recursive function (`y`) which you can reuse for other recursive functions/problems.